# Duda con calculo de pagina en paginador de php

Tags: php

Me he hecho un paginador a mano para filtrar la cantidad de resultados de una consulta a mysql que cuando tenia muchos registros tardaba demasiado.

este es el codigo que he usado:

```
function Paginador($Que,$Pagina,$Cuantos,$Maxpagina,$IdOrden) {
    $PagMax = round($Maxpagina / $Cuantos -1);
    if ($Pagina == $PagMax) { $UltimaPagina = 0; } else { $UltimaPagina = 1;}

$Paginador = '<div class="Paginador">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-left"';
    if ($Pagina != 0) { 
        $Paginador .='onclick="$(\'#'.$Que.'Pagina\').val(Number($(\'#'.$Que.'Pagina\').val()) - 1).change()" ';
     } else { 
         $Paginador .='style="color: #CCC;"\';'; } $Paginador .='></i>&nbsp;
    <select class="CuanPaginador" onchange="$(\'#'.$Que.'Cuantos\').val(this.value).change(); $(\'#'.$Que.'Pagina\').val(0)">
            <option '; if ($Cuantos == 5) { $Paginador .= "selected"; } $Paginador .=' value="5">5</option>
            <option '; if ($Cuantos == 50) { $Paginador .= "selected"; } $Paginador .=' value="50">50</option>
            <option '; if ($Cuantos == 100) { $Paginador .= "selected"; } $Paginador .=' value="100">100</option>
            <option '; if ($Cuantos == 500) { $Paginador .= "selected"; } $Paginador .=' value="500">500</option>
        </select>
&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-angle-right" ';
 if ($UltimaPagina >= 1) { $Paginador .=' onclick="$(\'#'.$Que.'Pagina\').val(Number($(\'#'.$Que.'Pagina\').val()) + 1).change()"';
 } else { $Paginador .='style="color: #CCC;"\'; ';
 } $Paginador .='></i>
 </div>
 <script>Ordenable(\''.$IdOrden.'\');</script>';
return $Paginador;
}
```

Los datos que le paso a esta función son:

```
$Que paso el nombre variable de los input ( para paginar )
$Pagina paso el numero de pagina en la que estoy
$Cuantos paso la cantidad de registros por pagina que quiero
$Maxpagina paso el numero total de registros que hay en la consulta
$Idorden es para activar una función de javascript que no tiene que ver con la paginación.
```

He tenido problemas con la ultima pagina ya que si pasaba a una pagina que ya no tenia resultados me sacaba la pagina en blanco, con lo que le he puesto un contador de paginas para saber cuantas paginas hay y en el caso de llegar a la ultima que no funcione mas el botón de siguiente pagina. Pero no se porque algo me dice que no estoy haciendo bien el calculo.

ese calculo lo saco en la 2ª y 3ª linea de codigo:

```
$PagMax = round($Maxpagina / $Cuantos -1);
if ($Pagina == $PagMax) { $UltimaPagina = 0; } else { $UltimaPagina = 1;}
```

Lo que estoy haciendo básicamente es: redondeo la operación resultante de dividir el numero de registros por la cantidad por pagina y Le Resto 1 (Le Resto ese uno porque al parecer en mysql el registro 1 equivale al 0 ) y si el numero de pagina en la que estoy es igual a la operación resultante de redondeo, anulo el botón de siguiente pagina.

El caso es que me da la sensación que me faltan registros cuando llego a la ultima pagina.

¿la operación para calcular la pagina seria esa?

Para calcular el mysql limit lo hago asi:

```
$STPagina= $_GET["pagina"] * $_GET["Cuantos"]; //calculo el registro por el que empezar el paginador
```

Aquí estoy pasando el numero de pagina ( que empieza en 0 ) y la cantidad de registros que quiero mostrar.

en al final de la consulta despues del ORDER BY pongo esto:

```
LIMIT $STPagina, ".mysqli_real_escape_string($Conectar, $_GET["Cuantos"])."
```

Lo mismo el fallo lo tengo aquí.

El numero total de registros lo saco sin aplicarle el limit ( ósea a todos los registros que existen en la tabla. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente:

Supongamos que la cantidad de registros es `12` y se listaran por página `5`, es decir:

```
$Maxpagina = 12; // NOTA: Considera cambiar el nombre a algo como $TotalRegistros ;)
$Cuantos = 5;

$Maxpagina / $Cuantos = 2.4 // <= con decimales
```

Al utilizar [`round`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php) se pierde la parte decimal:

```
round($Maxpagina / $Cuantos) = 2;
```

Pero para ver **TODOS** los items deberíamos tener recorrer `3` páginas, es decir:

- **Página 1**: del 1 al 5
- **Página 2**: del 6 al 10
- **Página 3**: del 11 al 12

### Solución:

Podrías usar [`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ceil.php) que:

> Redondea fracciones hacia arriba

```
$PagMax = ceil($Maxpagina / $Cuantos); // = 3
```

Pero como tus páginas van desde 0 (`cero`) en adelante, entonces:

```
$PagMax = ceil($Maxpagina / $Cuantos) - 1 // = 2;
```

**NOTA:** Recuerda que siempre debes validar los valores enviado por `GET`, `POST`, etc. para evitarte dolores de cabezas, por ejemplo, *Que $_GET["pagina"] y $_GET["Cuantos"] sean enteros*

Comment: Ya había cambiado el maxpagina por NRegistros para que fuera un poco mas claro leerlo XD. Ya he sustituido round por ceil y me surge una duda... ¿por que restas 1 en STPagina? el valor de pagina lo toma de un input que empieza por 0 ¿es necesario restar ese 1 igualmente? o en vez de 0 pongo al input 1 y que reste siempre? de momento aplicando el codigo tal cual no me muestra resultados ( supongo que será el 0 ese ) voy a probar a ver si encuentro el error, pero me parece super util tu respuesta ya que me confirmas mas o menos lo que tengo que poner. Mil gracias :)

Comment: Por cierto, te falta un ( en $STPagina = ($_GET["pagina"] - 1) * $_GET["Cuantos"]); :)

Comment: Respecto a los valores enteros. En principio si lo son, el cuantos viene de un select con valores fijos y el pagina es una suma o resta de 1 así que no debería dar decimales :)

Comment: @Killpe, con validar, me refiero a comprobar el tipo y valor de la variable. Esos valores al ser enviados por `GET`, son fácilmente modificables; basta con ver la `URL` y cambiar, por ejemplo `...&Cuantos=5` por `...&Cuantos=Hola`

Comment: Ahhh, pero el get lo uso solo mientras estoy probando que todo funcione, luego lo paso a post

Comment: @Killpe, el que sea `POST` no cambia el hecho de que deberías **validar**. Modificarlo puede ser un poco mas difícil (_para un usuario común_), pero se puede hacer y es por eso que **siempre** debes validar los datos recibidos.

Comment: Con filter? o te refieres al lugar de procedencia?

Comment: @Killpe, con respecto al primer comentario: resto uno porque imagine que la página empieza en `1` y no en `0`, si es cero, entonces no deberías restar a `$STPagina`, pero si restar a `$PagMax = ceil($Maxpagina / $Cuantos) - 1;`. Con respecto a tu ultimo comentario: me refiero a `filter_var` o [`castear`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php) y analizar el valor de la variable.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70274/discussion-between-marcos-and-killpe).

Answer (score 1):

El error es el siguiente:

```
$PagMax = round($Maxpagina / $Cuantos -1);
```

Sustitúyelo por:

```
$PagMax = round($Maxpagina / ($Cuantos -1));
```

Estás restando 1 al número de páginas. No al número de registros.

Comment: Si lo pongo así me manda a una pagina en blanco :( lo mismo el error lo tengo también en el mysql limit... voy a editar la pregunta y lo pongo también